# How do i create long/big Dictionaries in Swift? Error: Expression was to complex to be solved in reasnoble time

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, swift2

So i have this piece of code (fieldKey is a String)

```
    var request = [
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": [
            fieldKey : [
                "global": [],
                "aggs": [
                    "global": [
                        "aggs": [
                            "facet": [
                                "nested": [
                                    "path": "tags"
                                ],
                                "aggs": [
                                    "bar": [
                                        "filter": [
                                            "match": [
                                                "tags.name": fieldKey
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    "aggs": [
                                        "filtered": [
                                            "terms": [
                                                "field": "tags.name"
                                            ],
                                            "aggs": [
                                                "values": [
                                                    "terms": [
                                                        "field": "tags.value.raw",
                                                        "min_doc_count": 1
                                                    ]
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Im trying to create a JSON request for Elasticsearch server.

I get the "Expression was to complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" error.

This is when i tried to do this.

```
    var request = [
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": [String : AnyObject]()
    ]

    request["aggs"]![fieldKey] = [
            fieldKey : [
                "global": [],
                "aggs": [
                    "global": [
                        "aggs": [
                            "facet": [
                                "nested": [
                                    "path": "tags"
                                ],
                                "aggs": [
                                    "bar": [
                                        "filter": [
                                            "match": [
                                                "tags.name": fieldKey
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ],
                                    "aggs": [
                                        "filtered": [
                                            "terms": [
                                                "field": "tags.name"
                                            ],
                                            "aggs": [
                                                "values": [
                                                    "terms": [
                                                        "field": "tags.value.raw",
                                                        "min_doc_count": 1
                                                    ]
                                                ]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

But now i get the "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type "AnyObject?!"" error but i clearly used the "var" when creating the request? Does anyone know how to solve this? Is there any better way of creating such long Dictionaries/JSON files? Thanks

Comment: Put the data in a plist file, not hardcoded into the code.

Comment: Swift can't infer the type every time. Your literal dictionary is too complex to parse with its multi-nested values. Use a plist to JSON file to store the literals then read it back in code

Comment: Can you be more specific? I dont get it. Am i suppose to create a plist file in code and then turn convert it to a dictionary and then to JSON? Do i have to create a plist file by hand with all the known values and keys and then when i need it, convert it in to a dictionary and the change the values and keys that i only know at that moment, but wouldnt that create the same problems that i already have, with the immutable values? Because the "fieldKey" is a variable so just creating a plist file by hand and converting it in to dictionary wouldnt work without also changing the fieldKey.?

Comment: I hope you even understand what im saying.

Comment: You should be able to do `var request: [String : AnyObject] = [ ...` and it will figure it out.

Comment: You can create JSON data or Dictionary from struct.

Comment: You're assigning fieldKey to itself?